# Simplifying IF/ELSE IF/ELSE Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating my own validation code. I need to separate the if statements per input box for the error to show at the same time. I noticed that if it's on same if block, only the first error will show. Any way to simplify my code?

```js
flag = 0;
//first if
if (first_name.length == 0) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='firstname'").text('This field is required').css("display", "inline-block");
} else if (!first_name.match(name_regex)) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='firstname'").text('Firstname must be composed of letters only').css("display", "inline-block");
} else if (first_name.length < 3) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='firstname'").text('3 letters are required for lastname').css("display", "inline-block");
} else {
  flag = +1;
  $("label[for='firstname'").hide();
}

//second if
if (last_name.length == 0) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='lastname'").text('This field is required').css("display", "inline-block");
} else if (!last_name.match(name_regex)) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='lastname'").text('Lastname must be composed of letters only').css("display", "inline-block");
} else if (last_name.length < 2) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='lastname'").text('2 letters are required for lastname').css("display", "inline-block");
} else {
  $("label[for='lastname'").hide();
  flag += 1;
}

//third if
if (validateEmail(email)) {
  if (data.result) {
    $("input#userEmail").css("border-color", "#ac2925");
    $("label[for='email'").text('Email exists').css("display", "inline-block");
  } else {
    $("input#userEmail").css("border-color", "#e3e3e3");
    $("label[for='email'").hide();
    flag += 1;
  }
} else {
  $("input#userEmail").css("border-color", "#ac2925");
  $("label[for='email'").text('Please input a valid email address').css("display", "inline-block");;
}

//fourth if on verification success
if (flag == 3) {
  alert("All validation succeded!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unclear, explain more, what you want to achieve.

Comment: add return inside your every condition :)

Comment: if (first_name.length == 0) {
  flag = 0;
  $("label[for='firstname'").text('This field is required').css("display", "inline-block"); return;
}

Comment: Let say I want to redirect if all the validation succeeded. That code is working fine, I just want to know if it can be better.

The old code was only one block of IF:

if {} elseif {} elseif {} elseif {} else {}

But the problem is if I didn't put any letter on the 3 input box, only the error in the first input box will show. @Mr.x

Comment: set ur jquery syntax all into variable, then you no need to keep on repeat writing the same thing, just call the variable

Comment: this post should ask in CodeReview site.

Answer (score 0):

Just extract it into a function:

```
 function validate(inputName, labelName, minLetters, regex){
   const el = $(inputName);
   const label = $(labelName);
   if(!el || !!label) throw "validate: el not found";

  if(!el.val()){
    label.text("You need to fill in this!");
    return false;
  }

  if(regex && !el.val().test(regex)){
    label.text("The input contains invalid chars!");
    return false;
  }

 if(minLetters && el.val().length < minLetters){
   label.text("to short!");
   rerurn false;
 }

 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make the validation routine more generic. Please see following solution (note: untested):

```js
function validate(funcName, minLength) {
  if (this[funcName].length == 0) {
    $("label[for='"+funcName+"'").text('This field is required').css("display", "inline-block");
  } else if (!this[funcName].match(name_regex)) {
    flag = 0;
    $("label[for='"+funcName+"'").text(funcName +' must be composed of letters only').css("display", "inline-block");
  } else if (this[funcName].length < minLength) {
    $("label[for='"+funcName+"'").text(minLength + ' letters are required for ' + funcName).css("display", "inline-block");
  } else {
    $("label[for='"+funcName+"'").hide();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (validate("firstname", 2) 
    && validate("lastname", 3) 
    && validateEmail(email)
) {
  // everything seems to be OK. 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let me test this out :)

Answer (score -1):

My approaches will be :

1. Have individual If blocks for each validations by which all the validations will be checked. And build/append the validation error message on each check.
2. Write if else blocks within a function. That function can be called for each fields being validated. And the function will return validation error message for each invokation which can be appended into a single string.